# Force Vertical Scroll User Action to Manifest as Horizontal Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I am working on a portfolio site that is designed to scroll horizontally when the user scrolls vertically. This CSS (https://css-tricks.com/examples/HorzScrolling/) does NOT work for me. I can only find answers or fiddles that create a horizontal scrollbar, which is not what I am looking for.

My css rule looks like this:

```
 .container-scroll {
     width: auto;
     min-width: 100px;
     overflow-x: auto;
     position: relative;
     min-height: 100%;
 }
```

I am looking to emulate the horizontal scroll functionality of this site: http://yearinreview.hshtags.com/

Comment: The scrolling on that page is incredibly choppy on a mac trackpad, something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Made this a long time ago, it translates your mouse scrolling into a horizontal scroll and includes kinetic scrolling and adaptable to most broswers..

Just add what scrolling element you want into the bottom:

```
var hs = new HorizontalScroll(document.body);
```

instead of `document.body`

study it, learn from it ;)

[Codepin](http://codepen.io/Keleko/pen/QbQBLE)

To explain a little more:

There are many different mouse scroll events based on which browser is currently being used:

**mousewheel** (chrome)

**wheel** (IE)

**DOMMouseScroll** (firefox)

so to detect which one exists an attachment check is made with the element in question and then the function for the scroll event or `scrollEv` is attached, we will call this element elq:

```
var elq = document.getElementById('elementinquestion');
switch('object')
        {
            case typeof  elq.onmousewheel:
                elq.onmousewheel = scrollEv;
            break;
            case typeof  elq.onwheel:
                elq.onwheel = scrollEv;
            break;
            case typeof  elq.onDOMMouseScroll:
                elq.onDOMMouseScroll = scrollEv;
            break;
            case typeof  elq.DOMMouseScroll:
                elq.DOMMouseScroll = scrollEv;
            break;
        }
```

Once we have attached to the correct mousewheel event we can start our logic by reading the event object passed into the function:

```
var scrollEv = function(eventObject)
{
   eventObject.preventDefault(); //prevent default scrolling action
}
```

the properties in the event object we are looking for will also depend on the browser, also the values will differ between firefox and chrome/IE/Safari.

**eventObject.wheelDelta** (IE/chrome/Safari)

**eventObject.deltaY** (Firefox)

**eventObject.detail** (old IE)

to balance all of these so they come around similiar values for the scrolling to be fluid requires some math.. with `wheelDelta` we need to devide by 60 as this value will be high, with `deltaY` this value will be at the opposite spectrum.. so must do a inverse on it by multiplying by -1, detail just needs to be inversed and divided by 2, EX:

```
var delta = 0;
  if (eventObject == null)
  {
    eventObject = window.event;
  }
  if (typeof eventObject.wheelDelta != 'undefined')
  {
    if(eventObject.wheelDelta < -50)
    {
      eventObject.wheelDelta = -30;
    }
    else if(eventObject.wheelDelta > 50)
    {
      eventObject.wheelDelta = 30;
    }
    delta = eventObject.wheelDelta/60;
  }
  else if(typeof eventObject.deltaY != 'undefined')
  {
    if(eventObject.deltaY < -50)
    {
      eventObject.deltaY = -30;
    }
    else if(eventObject.deltaY > 50)
    {
      eventObject.deltaY = 30;
    }
    delta = eventObject.deltaY*(-1);
  }
  else if (typeof eventObject.detail != 'undefined')
  {
    delta = -eventObject.detail/2;
  }
```

now we can use this value to set our scrolling. our scrolling comes from 2 different properties in the element, also based on browser:

**elq.scrollLeft**

**elq.offsetLeft**

to move the element in question we will simply take our ending value of delta and add it to the scrollLeft:

```
if(typeof elq.scrollLeft != 'undefined')
{
  elq.scrollLeft += delta;
}
else if(elq.offsetLeft)
{
  elq.scrollLeft += delta;
}
```

and thats it, a cross browser scroll system that overwrites the default to horizontal :)